# HBase backed by S3

Tags: amazon-s3, hbase

I just read about being able to use HBase that is backed by S3 as the filesystem. 
I also read elsewhere that S3 is blob storage and lacks functionality to append to a file. Now minus any append functionality I am unable to understand how HBase can use S3 as the underlying filesystem. For e.g. what happens at S3 layer when I add a single new column to HBase?
Please help with my confusion!

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

If you add a small column, my understanding is that HBase will not immediately modify the underlaying storage.
Instead, hbase will (1) write the addition of a column / cell into a write ahead log WAL persistently and then (2) also modify the memcache.
When the memcache gets flushed to disk, only then will HBase modify the underlying data in relatively large chunks (which is well suitable to storage implementations such as S3 and HDFS).

Comment: When running HBase backed by S3, the WAL is still written to the HDFS of the EMR cluster.  Therefore, for the WAL it is possible to append to a file.  The writes to S3 are done asynchronously in large chunks as described here, append to a file is not needed therefore.